# What is the easiest way to replace Rust's thread_rng() generator with a seeded generator for tests?

Tags: random, rust

I have a large amount of code that uses `rand::thread_rng()`. I would like to make this code behave deterministically in tests using something like `StdRng::seed_from_u64(...)`. I'm aware that the 'correct' solution to this problem is to pass around a random number generator to all of my code which I can change at runtime, but changing hundreds of functions to take a new parameter isn't really feasible for me right now. Is there a simple way to just configure `thread_rng` to be deterministic or make my own version of it?

Comment: Are you expecting to reset the RNG in between each test? Or will the tests run in a deterministic order on deterministic threads so you only need to initialize each thread's RNG once?

Comment: I don't think there's any hook to take control of the `thread_rng`. You'd have to go and update the `THREAD_RNG_KEY` static, and then it's a *very specific* concrete type.

Comment: @JohnKugelman resetting between tests is probably ideal, especially for things like benchmark tests where getting the same sequence of numbers for each iteration will improve consistency.

Comment: According to [the docu](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html), `ThreadRng` is re-seeded every 64kiB of random data. This means, even if you manage to seed it, it will become indeterministic again after 64kiB.

Comment: You could provide your own `rand` crate that re-exports the original `rand` crate, but re-implements `thread_rng` to be more deterministic.